# Is it possible to extract image src attribute from the HTML output by a WordPress shortcode?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am trying to extract the img src attribute contained in the HTML that is generated by the following shortcode from an Instagram Wordpress plugin:

```
do_shortcode('[instagram-feed type=user id="'.get_company_field( 'instagram_id' ).'" num=1 cols=1 width=100 widthunit=% height=300 heightunit=px carousel=true carouselarrows=false carouselpag=false imagepadding=0 imagepaddingunit=px showfollow=false showheader=false showlikes=false showcaption=false hoverdisplay="date, location, likes" includewords="'.get_company_field( 'instagram_keyword' ).'"]');
```

I want to then put the URL of the image src attribute into a variable ($src) that I can output with PHP as the CSS background-image URL of an element.  For example:

```
echo '<header style="background-image: url('.$src.');" class="job_listing-entry-header listing-cover has-image">';
```

I am finding it difficult to extract the img src attribute.  Not sure if this can be done from the output of the shortcode.

I have tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
function sl_instagram_image() {
    $html = do_shortcode('[instagram-feed type=user id="'.get_company_field( 'instagram_id' ).'" num=1 cols=1 width=100 widthunit=% height=300 heightunit=px carousel=true carouselarrows=false carouselpag=false imagepadding=0 imagepaddingunit=px showfollow=false showheader=false showlikes=false showcaption=false hoverdisplay="date, location, likes" includewords="'.get_company_field( 'instagram_keyword' ).'"]');
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($html);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    $src = $xpath->evaluate("string(//img/@src)");
    echo '<header style="background-image: url('.$src.');" class="job_listing-entry-header listing-cover has-image">';
} 

add_action( 'listify_content_job_listing_header_before', 'sl_instagram_image');
```

Comment: if you need only the src attribute, why dont you write a jQuery script that collets you all of them, with the $.each method, and you can do whatever you just want with them

Comment: Not sure how to do that. Any suggestions Richard?

Comment: But I'm not sure whether the do_shortcode function is generating html from which the img src attribute can be extracted in the first place. In other words, I'm not sure whether the do_shortcode function outputs a string that can be stored in a variable. Any thoughts?

Comment: does the `do_shortcode()` function already displays the images on your website?

Comment: Richard, yes echo do_shortcode() displays an image or  images (depending on parameters) on my site, but I want to extract the img src attribute and place it into a variable like $src.